# Converting survey data to numerical data in R

Tags: r, dataset, survey

I have some survey data which measures trust where each respondent for each country answers "tend to trust it", "tend not to trust it" or "don't know".

The data is time-series, cross country and I would like to convert it so for each year there is one numerical value per variable.

I have downloaded the data in SPSS format and put into R using the read.spss function but I am now stuck with how to change it.

I have a formula below for net trust but no idea what commands or packages I would require to do this in R.

"Net trust = ￼ Trust/(Trust + Mistrust + Don't know) - Mistrust/(Trust + Mistrust + Don't know)"

Apologies if this question has been posted before but I would really be grateful for some advice.

Cheers!

```
structure(list(qb1_2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree", "Tend to        disagree"
), class = "factor"), qb1_3 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree", 
"Tend to disagree", "Totally disagree"), class = "factor"), qb1_4 = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
   "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree"), class = "factor"), qb2_1 =   structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Very important", 
    "Fairly important", "Not very important"), class = "factor"), 
    qb2_2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Very important", "Fairly important"), class = "factor"), 
    qb2_3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Very important", "Fairly important"), class = "factor"), 
    qb2_4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Very important", "Fairly important", "Not very important"
    ), class = "factor"), qb2_5 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Very important", "Fairly important", 
    "Not very important"), class = "factor"), qb3_1 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
    "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree", "Totally disagree"), class = "factor"), 
    qb3_2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree"
    ), class = "factor"), qb3_3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree", 
    "Tend to disagree"), class = "factor"), qb3_4 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
    "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree", "Totally disagree"), class = "factor"), 
    qb3_5 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree", 
    "Totally disagree"), class = "factor"), qb3_6 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
    "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree", "Totally disagree", 
    "DK"), class = "factor"), qb3_7 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
    "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree", "Totally disagree", 
    "DK"), class = "factor"), qb4_1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Totally agree", 
    "Tend to agree", "Tend to disagree"), class = "factor"), 
    qb4_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Totally agree", "Tend to agree"), class = "factor"), 
    qb5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("On a case by case basis", 
    "Always, in every case"), class = "factor"), qb6.1 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not mentioned", 
    "Mentioned"), class = "factor"), qb6.2 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Not mentioned", 
    "Mentioned"), class = "factor"), qb6.3 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Not mentioned", 
    "Mentioned"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("qb1_2", "qb1_3", 
"qb1_4", "qb2_1", "qb2_2", "qb2_3", "qb2_4", "qb2_5", "qb3_1", 
"qb3_2", "qb3_3", "qb3_4", "qb3_5", "qb3_6", "qb3_7", "qb4_1", 
"qb4_2", "qb5", "qb6.1", "qb6.2", "qb6.3"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share some sample data, preferably in a copy/pasteable format. Something like `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, ]))` for the first 10 rows is usually good.

Comment: Tend to agree    Totally disagree Totally agree    Tend to agree    Tend to agree    Tend to agree    Tend to disagree
   [8] Tend to agree    Totally agree    Tend to disagree Tend to agree    Tend to agree    Tend to agree    Tend to agree   
  [15] Totally agree    Tend to agree    Totally agree    Tend to disagree Tend to agree    T

Comment: (a) Please edit the data into your question and format it with code formatting. (b) I think you cut off the front of the output. It should start with `structure(`.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I have edited into the question.. however the output i received from the command was substantially to large for the character limit in the question box so i have reduced it

Comment: We will need the whole output for it to be really useful. Looks like you've got **a lot** of columns, let's change the command to `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, 1:10]))` to use only the first 10 rows and first 10 columns. Feel free to edit the subset to make it appropriate.

Comment: Is this more helpful?

Comment: Much better. Observations: Looks like likert scale data, with some scales about agreement, some about mentions, some about frequency, some about importance. So we'll need to organize those in the correct orders. Your columns are `"qb1_2", "qb1_3"`, etc., What do these numbers mean? You mention respondents and countries in your question, but I don't see any indication of those in your data. Where is that info?

Comment: Great. So "qbl_2", "qbl_3" are variables measuring perception of public security. The dataset is from the 2017 European Barometer and there are 28093 obs. of 476 variables. Included are variables which record the country/sample id and the unique respondent ID. Would you like me to provide the data for these?

Comment: I'd love for you to provide enough variables in the question so that an answer using that data is useful. You say *"I would like to convert it so for each year there is one numerical value per variable"*, so, I assume you should at least include the `year` variable. If you feel confident in how to deal with country and sample id, you can omit them. If you want help with country and sample id, you should include them. Perhaps read [How to Create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Help Center for  more guidance.

Comment: Also, since most of your variables have a small number of levels, I think you can stop using `droplevels` in the `dput` command - that should give a more complete picture, hoepfully without being *too* long. Perhaps something like `dput(your_data[1:10, c("year", "country", "sample_id", "qb1_2", "qb2_1", "qb5")])`? Just a few example response columns and the pertinent ID and description columns. Correcting to whatever the column names are in your actual data, of course.